# Javascript - Checking if variable has been set gives me undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect if a variable - play_status - has been set or not in javascript like this..

```
$lg.on('afterslide', function(event, prevIndex, index){

    if (play_status) {
        console.log('Play Defined')
    }

    iframe = $('.inner .item').eq(index).find('.vimeo').get(0);
    var player = $f(iframe);

    player.addEvent('ready', function(index) {

        player.addEvent('play', function() {
            var play_status = index;
        });

    });

});
```

But when I run it for the first time (when no variable is set) then I get the following error...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: play_status is not defined
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: looks like you only declared play_status when you add event play to player, so its not defined outside that scope

Comment: Thanks Chris, it was indeed a scope issue. Want to make your comment into an answer and I can mark it correct?

Comment: thx, i posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you only declared play_status when you add event play to player, so its not defined outside that scope

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)